# How to delete part of string starting with slash

Tags: perl

How I want to remove all string after slash using perl script? let say I have input file as below

For example:

```
hdkhehfkf/kfkjhoer
082734708/92740234
```

The output that i want is

```
hdkhehfkf
082734708
```

here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file  = "file.sv";
my $dirname       = "../../../folder/";

open ( OUTFILE, ">uncompile_test.txt" );
main ();
close OUTFILE;


sub main {
   my @array;

   open( my $fh, "<", "$dirname/$file")
       or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";

   while(<$fh>) { 
       push @array, $_; 
   } 

   close $fh;

   print OUTFILE " ", @array;   
}
```

Comment: please provide your code not only what you want

Comment: i update my question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the last slash in the string and everything after it

```
$string =~ s{.*\K/.*}{};
```

where `\K` drops all previous matches, so that they aren't "consumed" (from the string) so we don't have to capture and put back the first `.*`. See "*Lookaround Assertions*" [in Extended Patterns in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) for `\K`. We need that first `.*` in order to get to the last `/`, by the greediness of `*`.

To remove the first slash in the string and everything after it

```
$string =~ s{/.*}{};
```

I use `{}{}` delimiters to not have to escape `/` in patterns.

For your example either of these works.  They both change `$string`, which you can then print.

(If this is about working with paths then I suggest to use some of the good modules for that)

---

*The question got edited substantially, with code added*

To run this for every line of a file, and save output in another file

```
open my $fh_out, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";
open my $fh,     '<', $file    or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    print $fh_out s{.*\K/.*}{}r;
}

close $_ for $fh, $fh_out.
```

where I use the [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) `/r`, for "*non-destructive substitution*", with which the changed string is returned (and original left unchanged), just as needed to print directly to the file.

This removes the last `/` and all after it, the first case above; change to `s{/.*}{}r` if needed.

A few comments on the code in the question

- Always pass to a sub all that it needs from outside; relying on the sub to "see" variables from the surrounding scope is outright dangerous. In your case that would mean

  ```
  sub process_file_to_output {          # find a suitable name
      my ($dir, $file, $fh_out) = @_;
      ...
  }
  ```

  and you'd call it as

  ```
  process_file_to_output($dirname, $file, $outfile_handle);
  ```

  where `$outfile_handle` is the (lexical!) filehandle for the output file, if you wish to open the output file in the caller as in the question.
- Naming a sub `main` isn't very informative.  Choosing good names for variables and functions (and other program elements) turns out to be very important in programming.
- Use lexical filehandles and three-argument open for the output file, and check the `open` call, just as you nicely do for the input file (in the sub)

Comment: I edit my question. can you please review it again? thanks

Comment: @daffodil Oh, I see.  Your code doesn't show where to do this -- do you mean to make these changes to each line of the input file?

Comment: yup, the code above doesn't do anything. it just print out the the contents of the file. Need help on how want to make changes to show just like the output above

Comment: @daffodil OK, but make changes to what?  To every line of the file?

Comment: @daffodil Added some comments on the code in the question

Answer (score 1):

You could try splitting your input string on `/`, and then just retaining the first part after the split:

```
my $input = 'hdkhehfkf/kfkjhoer';   
my @parts = split /\//, $input;
print $parts[0];
```

This prints:

```
hdkhehfkf
```

Comment: Perl isn't PHP, you are allowed to combined expressions. `(split '/', 'hdkhehfkf/kfkjhoer')[0]` does the same, but shorter.

Comment: @daxim Believe it or not, I don't really know PHP or Perl `:P`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [substitution operator](http://p3rl.org/perlop#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer).

Expression

```
'hdkhehfkf/kfkjhoer' =~ s|/.*||r
```

returns string

```
'hdkhehfkf'
```